# variable is not affected in shell

Tags: shell

```
ls -l ${1}/${2}/${i}*| awk '{  print  $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9}' | ( while read Taille Mois Jour HeureOuAnnee Fichier

         do
            DateFichierEntreHierAujourdhui $Mois $Jour $HeureOuAnnee
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
                  NbFicREcu_links=`expr ${NbFicREcu_links} + 1`
            fi                
         done

         if [ $NbFicREcu_links -eq 0 ]
         then
            echo 'i am here 1'
            echo ${i}
            INT14_KO_FR=1
         else   
            echo 'i am here 2'
         fi
         )       
         fi
echo "1- in the end of the fonction INT14_KO_FR=${INT14_KO_FR}"
```

This piece of code detects if it lacks of specific files. In fact, when we go into the block which prints 'i am here 1', i want to do INT14_KO_FR=1. But when I quit this loop, INT14_KO_FR is always 0, the initial value. The code enter into 'i am here 1' for 2 times. It's really weird, thank u guys for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe is run in a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), so any [variables set inside it are not in scope for the outside code](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). Different workarounds are mentioned there, depending on which language features you are familiar with and whether you need to be POSIX compatible.

Comment: That's really helpful! But I'd better not destroy the previous work done by the others. Is it possible to do this affection? with a pipe in a subshell?

Comment: If you want to keep the value you have to either store it in a file or use a different structure, as explained in the last link.